# Display Data in a Jtable upon Row Selection from Another JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have read one of the question in this website. and since I had the same problem with the one who asked the same question as mine, I want to do a follow up question. HOW DO YOU PUT THIS INTO CODE:

- Ask the master table what its selected row is (getSelectedRow()).
- Convert this view row index to a model row index (convertRowIndexToModel()).
- Ask the model for the data at this index, ands extract the ID of the data. The model should be a class that you wrote, extending AbstractTableModel.
- Then get the data to display in the three sub-tables from this ID, and change the model (or the data contained in the model) of these three tables.

Thanks in advance. i am quite having a hard time in this part of my program. since i only know about

```
tablePersonalProperty.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

when displaying all the items from the table. what i need is to DISPLAY the items with the same id from what i have chosen from the main table...

Comment: Execute a SQL query that returns only the rows having the given ID, and call the methof you only know about. You could also read the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Are you asking how you can implement the model for getting the selection right or how you can get the data for other tables depending upon your selection ?

Comment: welcome to this forum, just: please don't shout at us :-)

Comment: Yes. i am trying to get the data from a main table depending on what i have selected. the information will be reflected on another table from a tabbed pane. the main table is just my reference.

Answer (score 0):

Before we can help you write code, we need more information.
Do your tables both have exactly the same columns?
Are you using your own custom data model already?  If not, then you probably need to try that on your own. I can't write this for you since I don't know what you need to include in your model.  If you are using netbeans, then you can use the form designer to help you write the table model.  Just look at the properties of the JTable after you add it to the JFrame of JPanel.  I ended up creating my own anyway, but the code that Netbeans generated helped get me started.

Comment: I have a (main) table on my Jframe. it has 3 columns (ClientID, LastName, FirstName). i use this table to view the details of the listed clients. on the same frame, i have 4 tabbed panes. the first two consists of textboxes. everytime i click/ choose from the main table, information related to that client appears on the textboxes.

Comment: Isn't the problem arise from my query? im a bit confused. THank You again for the response

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will help you to do what you are looking for, it show how to move table row from one table to another in a click event in rows,

```
public class InsertRows{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  new InsertRows();
  }

  public InsertRows(){
  final JTable table, table2;
  final DefaultTableModel model, model2;
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Inserting rows in the table!");
  String data[][] = {{"Vinod","100"},{"Raju","200"},{"Ranju","300"}};
  String col[] = {"Name","code"};
  Object[][] selrowData = {};   
  model = new DefaultTableModel(data,col);
  model2 = new DefaultTableModel(selrowData,col);

  GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(2,1); 

  table = new JTable(model);
  table2 = new JTable(model2);
  //Insert first position
  model.insertRow(0,new Object[]{"Ranjan","50"});
  //Insert 4 position
  model.insertRow(3,new Object[]{"Amar","600"});
  //Insert last position
  model.insertRow(table.getRowCount(),new Object[]{"Sushil","600"});


    ListSelectionModel cellSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
    cellSelectionModel.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    cellSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        String selectedData = null;
        String selectedData2 = null;
    Object[][] val = {};
        int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
        int selectedColumns = table.getColumnCount();

        model2.insertRow(0,new Object[]{(String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedColumns-selectedColumns),(String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedColumns-1) });   
      }
    });

  frame.setLayout(gl);
  frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
  frame.add(new JScrollPane(table2));
  frame.setSize(600,600);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to move the data from your ResultSet into the model shown in the code Vinesh posted.  Pull the data out of the ResultSet and place into an Object array.